# How to pass vector<pair<int,int> >v[]

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, stdvector

I'm trying to pass a  `vector<pair<long,long> > adj[n]` to another function called short but it gives me error but I've written code like this before so I don't why this is giving an error now

error: invalid declarator before ‘adj’

error: expected ‘)’ before ‘adj’

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

  void short(vector<pair<long,long> >adj[], int n){
    vector<long>dist(n+1,INT_MAX);
    vector<long>parent(n+1, -1);
    dist[1] = 0;
    parent[1] = 1;
    priority_queue<pair<long,long>,vector<pair<long,long> >,greater<pair<long,long> > > pq;
    pq.push(mp(0,1));
    vector<bool>flag(n+1, false);
    while(!pq.empty()){
        long u = pq.top().S;
        pq.pop();
        flag[u] = true;
        for(auto it = adj[u].begin(); it!=adj[u].end(); it++){
            long v = (*it).F;
            long wt = (*it).S;
            if(!flag[v] && dist[u] +wt < dist[v]){
                dist[v] = dist[u]+wt;
                pq.push(mp(dist[v],v));
                parent[v] = u;
            }
        }
    }
    print(parent, 1);
}



int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0);
    long n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<pair<long,long> > adj[n+1];
    long u, v, w;
    loop(i,m){
        cin >> u >> v >> w;
        adj[u].pb(mp(v,w));
        adj[v].pb(mp(u,w));
    }
    short(adj,n);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an array of vectors? If you already use vectors, just make a vector of vectors?

Comment: @UnholySheep I see that on g__ks4g__ks all the time, probably inspired from there

Comment: Rename function `short` to something else. `short` is a [C++ fundamental type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). You cannot use it as the name of an identifier.

Comment: @tommo I have added it as an answer. Consider upvoting and [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: @UnholySheep This looks like a competitive programming solution. There, coding speed matters so that would explain the usage of `bits/stdc++.h` include, `mp` (make_pair), `pb` (push_back) macros and also the vector of arrays. Why waste time type the extra `vector<>` and `resize(n)` instead of `[n]`  when you know what its size is. I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void short(vector<pair<long,long> >adj[], int n){
```

Rename function `short` to something else. `short` is a C++ fundamental type. You cannot use it as the name of an identifier.

(Originally posted as comment under question. Adding it as answer as per [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment))

Answer (score 0):

actually when we define the vector with some size we use parenthesis instead of that square bracket...

vector>adj(n)
 ..this is the correct format ..

and also change your function name to something else as short is a keyword in c++

hope you get it:)